# Why does axios catch errors on successful Spotify API calls?

Tags: express, axios, spotify, netlify

I'm having a weird and frustrationg error trying to add songs to spotify via the API.

The API call is successful and the songs are added correctly, however it returns a "TypeError:  Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

This is the code I believe should be correct.

```
router.post('/addSongs', async (req, res) => {
    var access_token = req.query.access_token;
    var playlist_id = req.query.playlist_id;
    var songs = req.body.songs;

    try {
        var retVal = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlist_id}/tracks`,
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                uris: songs
            }
        });

        res.send(retVal);  
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);

        res.status(error.response.status).send(error);

    }
});
```

One solution I've found which makes it more frustrating is that the following change makes it work perfectly although it makes me feel horrible:

```
...
} catch (error) {
    res.status(200).send("whatever");
}
...
```

I'm using Express and Netlify-lambda and I'm rather new to all of it.

Note it also works correctly and prints the error status and message when there actually is an error, and I get a "Converting circular structure to JSON" error if I only print the error

Comment: I guess the response does not have a body, so the data is undefined, It just has a response code, I assume

Comment: Print out your `error` in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone founds this, I solved it. The issue was that axois threw an error when I tried to return the `retVal` variable. I think it was an empty string.

Solution:

```
    res.send(retVal)

    change to:

    res.status(201).send()
```